# Декомпилятор для С++

Tags: c++, декомпиляция

Я учусь С++ и тут узнал, что существуют декомпиляторы. Я читал, что невозможно обратно получить исходный код из откомпилированной программы на С++. Это так? Если да, то можно ли сделать так, чтобы это невозможно было? И какие программы декомпилируют программы на С++?

Comment: Можно получить только код на assambler с помощью диссамсамблера

Answer (score 8):

Полноценная декомпиляция для C++ в общем случае невозможна: имена переменных и функций не сохраняются.

Comment: а если я хочу защитить свой проект от декомпиляции? то это возможно или просто смириться нужно?

Comment: Смиритесь. Надо будет - расковыряют так или иначе.

Comment: @Developer Вопрос упирается в соотношение стоимость взлома/полученная выгода :) Текст на ЯВУ не получится, это понятно, но опять же - раз процессор какой-то код выполняет - то этот код уже известен :)

Comment: А можно хоть как то защитить от декомпиляции или нет?

Comment: @Developer использование ООП осложняет анализ, как и индусский код.

Comment: @Developer, обфускация ? Только зачем Вам это ?

Comment: @isnullxbh рискну предположить что достаточно смышленный компилер обфускацию выкинет...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ООП упрощает анализ. И сильно. Вы сравните классы логические со своими функциями и набор непонятно чего всё в одном файле, все переменные глобальные.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не могу согласится/не согласится, потому как с данной темой знаком поверхностно. Хотя вообще, не совсем понимаю, почему компилятор должен от нее избавится - если есть время - можете подробнее объяснить, для общего развития будет всем полезно. Но меня больше интересует вопрос _зачем_. Коммерческим фирмам - ок, любителям зловредов - ок, но человеку, который "учусь C++" (извини меня, Developer) - не понятно ))

Comment: @pavel вы анализировали в Иде программы, работающие с std::string/list/vector? Как по мне - отличная обфускация выходит. Я не говорю про более сложные классы.

Comment: @isnullxbh компилятор вполне может производить какие-то вычисления на этапе компиляции, сталкивался неоднократно. Аналогично и обфускация в виде разбиения строк на подстроки и т.д. может быть опущена.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов угу, именно в IDA и анализировал. По мне всё неплохо читабельно. Вот vector https://godbolt.org/g/hXA03h по мне так все вызовы сразу видны. А IDA всё же поумнее чем мы на глаз)

Comment: а способ защиты от декомпиляции - вынести код на сервер и пусть там считает).

Comment: @pavel еще можно вынести часть расчетов на usb-устройство (в стиле sim-карты), или в виртуальную машину (WMProtect например).

Answer (score 1):

Дизассемблер IDA PRO - инструмент для исследования, отладки и, при необходимости, модификации уже скомпилированных программ, когда нет исходных текстов. Декомпиляторы в псевдокод С++, конечно, имеются (IDA тоже это умеет), но проку от них будет мало. Только ассемблер!

Вот скриншот IDA PRO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Продублирую и тут, раз вы дублируете ответ: не единственный и не незаменимый.

Comment: @insolor так я без задней мысли написал, как есть. Если вы можете предложить серьёзные альтернативы IDA, как минимум с такими же широкими возможностями и удобствами для исследования бинарников, то я тоже буду рад про них узнать. За исправление опечатки, кстати, спасибо.

Comment: "как минимум с такими же широкими возможностями и удобствами для исследования бинарников" - нет, так не пойдет. В ответе вы написали только про "единственный и незаменимый", я отвечаю конкретно на это. В большинстве случаев не нужно всех этих широких возможностей, достаточно более простых инструментов - а таких простых инструментов, способных заменить IDA полно. Если нужен список, то вот: radare2, Cutter, Ghidra, x64dbg, OllyDbg, и т.д.

Comment: @insolor а ещё WinHex, PE Tools, ImpRec и другие специальные инструменты... Это всё дополнительные средства, которые могут понадобиться, но идут в списке, начиная с номера 2 после IDA. Олькой, кстати, я в своё время очень активно пользовался, когда IDA ещё не имел встроенного отладчика. Но должен заметить, что OllyDbg мне больше нравился, чем отладчик IDA. Гораздо удобней в нём было "на лету" патчить отлаживаемую программу. Жаль что проект этот был давным-давно заброшен.

Comment: "Это всё дополнительные средства, которые могут понадобиться, но идут в списке, начиная с номера 2" - это конкретно ваш стиль работы, это не значит, что это единственный путь. Для многих задач достаточно простого дизассемблера, не уходящего в анализ на несколько минут, а дизассемблирующего конкретно то что ему укажут. Того же radare2 например. Так легко IDA становится инструментом номер 2, который достаешь только для каких-то сложных задач.

Comment: "Для многих задач достаточно простого дизассемблера, не уходящего в анализ на несколько минут, а дизассемблирующего конкретно то что ему укажут." Ну если с позиции экономии ресурсов на слабом ПК, то может такой подход и верен. При всех своих непревзойдённых достоинствах, IDA достаточно тяжеловесен, это следует признать. Но если железо нормальное, то из моего опыта те несколько минут ожидания анализа экономят в последствии гораздо больше времени. Тем более, что заранее не знаешь, с кодом какой степени коварности придётся столкнуться. Но тут уж кто как привык работать...

Answer (score 0):

Ну если очень хочется защитить программу от взлома, то есть специальные программы-обфускаторы. Они запутывают инструкции процессора, в которые собирается программа. Тот, кто захочет взломать Вашу программу, будет дезассемблировать Ваш исполняемый файл. Получить текст программы на ЯВУ он не сможет из-за особенностей С++. Ассемблер нормальным людям итак читать сложно, а тут он ещё и превращён в жуткую кашу обфускатором. Это хакера помучает изрядно. Но остановить полностью навряд ли сможет. И при этом есть повышенный риск ошибок и замедление быстродействия в обработанном обфускатором куске кода. Так что ценность метода под вопросом, если конечно Вы не проект ААА-класса разрабатываете. Там все средства хороши.

Comment: "нормальным людям" а кто такой нормальный человек? И можно примеры таких программ, которые реально запутывают ассемблерный код до нормального уровня, вроде бы все оффлайн игры взломали поэтому и вопрос.

Comment: @pavel естественно все оффлайн игры взломали. Обфускация  - это не шифрование. Невозможно высчитать эффективность её применения с помощью математики. Шифрование гарантирует, что взломщик не сможет вообще ничего понять в полученном им шифрованном тексте до тех пор пока не получит/подберёт/угадает ключ. Взломостойкость шифра определяет произойдёт ли это вообще, и если да, то сколько времени шифр продержится гарантированно. А запутанный код хакер начнёт разбирать с первой секунды. Просто он будет это делать медленнее, чем читал бы не запутанный код. А насколько медленнее - зависит от хакера)

Comment: Допустим некую игру хотят взломать 3 хакера: Вася, Петя и Вова. Вася в запутанном коде вообще не разберётся из-за плохих навыков, Петя потратит 2 месяца чтобы разобраться, а Вова 1 неделю. В итоге всё зависит от того, какой хакер возьмётся за взлом. И от того посчитает ли он нужным тратить своё время на Ваш проект. Последнее - самое важное. Почти все проекты ААА класса взломаны. А вот среди программ и игр "второго эшелона" множество так и не покорились хакерам. Потому что тратить силы и время на второсортный проект мало кому хочется. Всё упирается в то, насколько Ваш проект нужно взломать.

Comment: А по поводу "нормальных людей" - я имел ввиду, что языки высокого уровня ориентированы на удобство чтения человеком. Ассемблер ориентирован на эффективную работу с железом. Тексты на нём читать тяжелее, чем на ЯВУ для большинства программистов. Везде есть исключения, но даже для самых больших знатоков ассемблера, чтение текстов на нём - процесс более медленный, чем чтение текста на ЯВУ. Просто меньше информации в том же объёме текста и ниже уровень абстракции от железа.

Comment: А примеры обфускаторов:  Stunnix C++ Obfuscator, StarForce C++ Obfuscate, Morpher C/C++ Obfuscator, Semantic Design C und C++ Obfuscators. Об этих программах только слышал, сам не пользовался. Ибо проектов, для которых этот софт применять имело бы смысл, у меня не было. Поэтому оценить степень эффективности работы каждого не могу.

Comment: Для экзешников такие программы называются протекторами исполняемого кода. Примеры: Asprotect, EXECryptor, Themida - настоящая головная боль для взломщика платного софта! А ещё они небезопасны и могут приводить к дополнительным багам и крешам защищаемых ими приложений.